# Error con JSON al introducir ? desde Android en Realtimede Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Les cuento, estoy trabajando con java en android haciendo un tipo chat, mi duda o pregunta, es que cuando envió mensajes desde la tableta mi app truena por que introducir un ?, ¿saben si existe alguna validación para no suplantar el signo "?" ?. Uso un recycler para pintar los datos de la misma documentación de firebase.

Agradezco su atención de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de enviar tu mensaje aplicale un URLEncode y al recibirlo haz un decode antes de desplegarlo.

Agrega esto al evento que envía el mensaje:

```
String message="es.stackoverflow.com?";
String encoded=URLEncoder.encode(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
enviar(encoded);
```

Antes de desplegar el mensaje:

```
String decoded= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```